# Imported function does not exist when called within a map?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Got a function which I import and use thus:

```
const helpers = require('./helperFunctions');
console.log(helpers.sanitizeString("blah!&b;ah"));
```

> "blah and blah"

That's great! But now...

```
function podcastAudioDataFormatter(items) {
  let audioData = items.slice(0, 10).map(obj => ({
        duration: fixPodcastTime(obj),
        title: helpers.sanitizeString(obj.title),
        description: helpers.sanitizeString(obj.description),
      }));
  return (audioData);
}
```

> TypeError: helpers.sanitizeString is not a function

The thing that's confusing me is that fixPodcastTime is also a function, but defined locally, not imported.

Hmmm.. can anyone explain what might be happening here, why one works and not the other, where I've gone wrong and how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Is that import and the function you posted in the *same* file? And is `helpers` in the same scope as `podcastAudioDataFormatter`?

Comment: Looks like this happens when a module is called from another module.
In other words, podcastAudioDataFormatter lives in podFunctions, which defines/requires helpers at the top of the podFunctions, and is called by index.js.   
To be "belt and braces", I tried `const helpers = require('./helperFunctions')` at the top of all files. Still nothing.
Everything is OK when I redefine all my requires directly within the function. So I've done that, but I hadn't realised that "top of file" declarations don't propogate like that.  
In case it makes any difference, this is on AWS Lambda (nodejs 8.10)